# What is better from a quality and volume perspective: to connect a phone, tablet or laptop to a receiver?

Tags: audio, music

I want to connect one of my devices to an older analog receiver to play music at a party, so I expect relatively loud volumes. Does it matter in terms of quality and/or volume if I connect my phone, tablet or laptop and play through Spotify?

Comment: depends on your devices and their respective sound quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend to an extent on the sound device quality in each device, but given that most internet based streamed music is compressed, you'll be hard pressed to hear much difference based on hardware alone. Having said that, services like Pandora will use a higher audio compression when streaming via your cell phone data network, versus when streaming on a higher bandwidth wifi network. (Higher bandwidth results in less audio compression, which gives better audio quality.) I read a complaint on the Spotify forum that their streaming service consumes cell phone data, even when on a wifi network. To avoid that, and increase my chances of getting the highest bandwidth streaming experience, I'd choose a device that is not a cell phone.